# Syncing project to github does not sync java source files

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio

I am writing an android app using Android Studio, and I am trying to sync it to github.  I have tried through the GUI VCS menu and through terminal, but both have resulted in the directory where my .java files should be turning into what seems to be a file I cannot open in github.  So, my source files should be in `~/BrainGames/app/src/main/java/com/example/root/braingames/`, but github creates a file at `~/BrainGames/app/src/main/java/com/example/root/` called braingames and this file cannot be opened to see the source files.  I have tried remaking the repository through github and through Android Studio and I have tried syncing many times.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you pushed the files from your local machine into Github? After you create the repository, you need to push the files up.

Comment: Yes, I did but it made no change.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Github repo so we can see what it looks like? I'm having trouble understanding what's going on.

Comment: Sure, I actually tried a few more things and now the problem is the same but app is the directory that cannot be opened.  This is the repository: https://github.com/tgrossb/BrainGames

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai This repository was created using the basic instructions given by GitHub when you create a new project, but with "git add ." instead of "git add README.md"

Answer (score 0):

You should check your project directory, check all the files. If you have a Mac do `ls -a -l`. Check to see if you have multiple `.git` files, if you do, delete one of them. If you have multiple, it can cause this problem.

Comment: I only have one.

Comment: I actually just fixed it by removing the .git file and re-initiating, then doing "git add ." and "git add app".  Then, I added a new remote and pushed with the "--force" flag.

Comment: Well I hope I was able to help.